# Discord User History - Saving Multiple Things In A JSON File

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to set up a history command for when a player gets warned with a moderation bot. I have it where it saves it in a JSON file however I don't know how to save multiple cases for one player. Right now it just replaces the last warn.

```
//--Adds To Logs
let warnhist = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./historywarn.json", "utf8"));

warnhist[wUser.id] = {
 Case: `${wUser} was warned by ${message.author} for ${reason}`
};

fs.writeFile("./historywarn.json", JSON.stringify(warnhist), (err) => {
 if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

It saves like this without adding onto it every time:

```
{"407104392647409664":{"Case":"<@407104392647409664> was warned by <@212770377833775104> for 2nd Warn"}}
```

I need it to save like this:

```
{
"407104392647409664":{"Case":"<@407104392647409664> was warned by <@212770377833775104> for 1st Warn", "Case 2":"<@407104392647409664> was warned by <@212770377833775104> for 2nd Warn" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an array instead of an object. Try structuring your data a bit more too, so your JSON looks like this:

```
{ "<user id>": { "warnings": [...] }
```

Then instead of overriding the history every time with an assignment `warnhist[wUser.id] = ...` you can use `Array.prototype.push` to add a new one.

Taking a step back though, I don't think JSON is a good strategy to store this data, especially if it contains all warnings for all users. You need to load the entire JSON and read the file and write the file every single time you add a warning, and there could be conflicts if you have multiple instances of your service doing the same for a large number of users.

For a super similar API and storage format but better performance and consistency, try MongoDB instead of a plain JSON file.

Comment: Also, if he happen to use Discord.js-Commando, there is a built in SQLite provider included, which might be enough if it's a personal bot. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/first-steps